# serializing/deserializing derived objects using JSON.NET without using JsonProperty?

Tags: json.net

I'm using the NewtonSoft JSON.NET library for serializing the following class where DTOBase can hold derived instances.

```
public class Command
{         
    public DTOBase CommandDTO  { get; set; }                
}
```

Per [this article](http://james.newtonking.com/) you need to include the JsonProperty attribute so that the derived instances get deserialized properly

```
public class Command
{ 

  [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]  
  public DTOBase CommandDTO  { get; set; }       
 }
```

The question is whether there is any other way besides using an attribute to get the same result? I would prefer to not be coupled to the NewtonSoft library and json serialization in particular at the class level. Is there a way to specify some settings on the Serialize/Deserialize methods of the library at all to get the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TypeNameHandling` property can be set on `JsonSerializerSettings` when you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, settings)`.

If you only want the name included for derived objects set `TypeNameHandling` to `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.

Comment: Hi James, I tried this but it did not work, the serialized string does not contain the type information for the property like it does when I use the JsonProperty attribute.  v                          var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All};
string serializedInstance = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject,Formatting.None,settings);

Comment: Looks like I had an older version of te library. I upgraded to the latest one and the JsonSerializerSettings with TypeNameHandling.Auto works as expected.